# Токсические отношения или токсичные отношения?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Токсические отношения" или "токсичные отношения"?

Почему?

Comment: Ютуб завален роликами, в названии которых используется словосочетание "токсичные отношения". Обычно это ролики, где разбирают отношения с людьми, у которых имеется какое-либо нарушение характера (психопаты, социопаты, грандиозные и скрытые нарциссы, истерики и т. п.). Но часто встречаю в комментариях и в блогах словосочетание "токсические отношения".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Из словаря:

**ТОКСИЧНЫЙ,** -ая, -ое; -чен, -чна, -чно. Спец. Способный вызвать отравление. Т-ые вещества. <Токсичность, -и; ж. Большая, меньшая т. Т. газа.
**ТОКСИЧЕСКИЙ**, -ая, -ое. Биол., мед. 1. Ядовитый, отравляющий. Т-ие вещества. Т-ое действие никотина. 2. Вызываемый действием токсинов. Т-ое поражение нервной системы.

2. Итак, в толковых словарях (у Кузнецова и Ефремовой) указано только **относительное** значение, соответственно, **переносное** (качественное) значение не обозначено. Но слово в заданном сочетании используется именно в переносном значении.

[Статья на тему](https://dzen.ru/a/XtEjQ9Fg_2w0k9hk)

3. Какое же прилагательное **более корректно?** Обычно переносное значение имеют слова **с суффиксом Н**, а не суффиксом СК. Почему? Если посмотреть в толковом словаре Ефремовой, то можно отметить: суффикс СК обычно обозначает **общее отношение** к предмету (*ритмический*), а суффикс Н — отношение к **признаку предмета** (*ритмичный*).

И мы говорим: *Ритмическая структура предложения, но ритмичные движения*. Но сказать «ритмические движения» мы тоже можем. В то же время носитель языка скорее выберет  сочетание «ритмичные движения»

4. Вот и в нашем случае предпочтительным вариантом является слово ***«токсичный».***